# Laravel How to create calendar event using Cronofy

Tags: php, laravel, cronofy

In my `laravel`-application I want to include my `google-calendar` by using the [Cronofy API](https://docs.cronofy.com/developers/api/) and the package from [cronofy-php](https://github.com/cronofy/cronofy-php).

When I try to create an event, I get the error `422 Unprocessable Entity` but I don't really know why.

Here is my create/post request

```
$cronofy = new Cronofy\Cronofy([
    "client_id" => config('cronofy.client_id'),
    "client_secret" => config('cronofy.client_secret'),
    "access_token" => $access_token->value,
    "refresh_token" => $refresh_token->value
]);

$params = [
    'calendar_id' => (string)request()->calendar_id,
    'event_id' => (string)request()->event_id,
    'summary' => request()->summary,
    'description' => request()->description,
    'start' => request()->start,
    'end' => request()->end
  ];

$new_event = $cronofy->upsertEvent($params);

return response('event added!', $new_event);
```

I both tried without and with `(string)` on the "calendar_id" and "event_id" but with no luck.

So, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

There is more information on the reason for the `422` available to you in one of two ways.

1. The response body will contact a JSON object describing all of the errors that are preventing the request from being processed. [See error docs](https://docs.cronofy.com/developers/api/error-codes/#status-422)
2. In the [Cronofy Developer Dashboard](https://app.cronofy.com/developer_dashboard) you can see a full log of your API requests along with the same details of any errors.

This should help you understand which parameter value is causing the issue. The [create and update event docs](https://docs.cronofy.com/developers/api/events/upsert-event/) will give you guidance on allowed values and formats.

If you need further assistance you can also raise a ticket with our support team from the developer dashboard.

Comment: Ah ok nice! Was not aware of that :-) Now it works - even though its not syncing :-/